# Redux-form - Redirect after server response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, redux-form

I am using redux-form in react and I would like to redirect to other page after succesful server response ( res 200) . Here is full code with my class LoginForm:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  state = {
      redirectToNewPage: false
    }

  handleSubmit=({email='',password=''})=>{
    let error={};
    let isError=false;
    if(email.trim()===''){
      error.email='Required';
      isError=true;
    }   
    if(password.trim()===''){
      error.password='Required';
      isError=true;
    }
    if(isError){
      throw new SubmissionError(error);
      }
    else{
        //this.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true });  // <--- it will redirect
        fetch('/auth', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
          })
        })
        .then( function(res){
          console.log(res.status);
          if(res.status==200){
            console.log("REDIRECTING...");
            //this.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true }); // It will show error unknow function

          }
          else{
            console.log("ERROR");
          }
        })


      }
  }

  static propTypes={
    handleSubmit:React.PropTypes.func
  }

    render(){
      const {handleSubmit}=this.props;
      if (this.state.redirectToNewPage) {
       return (
               <Redirect to="/markers"/>
       )
      }
      return(
        <div className="container">
      <form className="form-login" onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit)}>
        <h2 className="form-login-heading">Login</h2>
          <Field name="email"  label="Email address"  component={renderField} type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
          <Field name="password"  label="Password"  component={renderField} type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    )
}

};
```

The problem is inside handleSubmit method. I can't use (this.setState()) inside .then after fetch:

```
.then( function(res){
          console.log(res.status);
          if(res.status==200){
            console.log("REDIRECTING...");
            //this.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true }); // It will show error unknow function

          }
          else{
            console.log("ERROR");
          }
```

I got an error :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of
>   undefined

Have you got any ideas how to do that?

Comment: It's a plain old JS scoping issue: using `.then( (res)=> {` rather than `.then( function(res){` should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Man it is working! Thank you!

Comment: @JesseKernaghan how can I set variable for example that boolean isError inside that function `.then( (res)=>{
          console.log(res.status);
          if(res.status==200){
            console.log("TAK");
            this.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true });

          }
          else{
            console.log("NIE");
            isError=true;
          }
        })`

That way it is not changing value outside .then() :/

Answer (score 1):

Although you got an answer in the comments, I feel like it is important to understand why you got this error. The reason is tied to the specific use of arrow vs normal functions in Js.

Whenever you use the `function` keyword in JS you are creating a new context and anytime you refer to `this` inside said function you will refer to that function context. What happens is that the function binds its own `this`.

This is one of the reasons arrow functions are great in these use cases. Using the `=>` syntax will allow you to use a function that does NOT create a new context and preserves the reference to `this` form the outer context. So it does not bind its own `this`.

Just to give you an idea of how nice arrow functions are, I will show you how your code could look like without it.

```
...
const that = this;

...

.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res.status);
  if(res.status==200){
    console.log("REDIRECTING...");
    that.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true });
  } else {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
})
```

Which used to be a widely used pattern, with arrow functions you don't need to do this anymore

```
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.status);
  if(res.status==200){
    console.log("REDIRECTING...");
    this.setState({ redirectToNewPage: true });
  } else {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
})
```

A good reference with full explanation can be [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thank you for that answer! But to be honest I don't get, why it is impossible inside  " .then() " change the variable that I got on the top of that method, for example isError. When I am doing inside  `else {
    console.log("ERROR");
    isError=true;
  }`

The value is not being changed outside

Comment: You should be able to change a variable that was defined before the `Promise`, but keep in mind that your code inside a `.then` is async. If you show me a little snippet of code so I can understand the issue better I can help out!

Comment: It is handleClick method, that is on the top, I would like to be able to show error message when the response is bad so I have to make isError=true there inside function  and make use of ` if(isError){
      throw new SubmissionError(error);
      }` somwhere in the code.

Comment: Well that's not the right approach, you should have a state variable handling errors, and you update that when your request fails. This way your UI can be updated whenever the state changes.